# How to style a TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I'm trying to style text in`TabLayout`. I'd like to managed the styles such as `font color, size and weight`, change the text therein from being set to **ALL CAPS**

How can I go about it?

```
TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Upload"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pics"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Vids"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Papers"));
```

I would like to attach the TabLayout to styles set in XML: something like:

Then I call it:

```
Button button = new Button(mContext);
button.setText("Add New BAG");
button.setTextAppearance(R.style.bttn_style);
button.setTextAppearance(R.style.custom_bttn_style);
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="custom_bttn_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00600f</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">\'Zilla Slab\', serif</item>
</style>
```

Vielen dank im voraus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate a custom view, where you will add all styles you want

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.icon_tab, null);
AppCompatTextView tv = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
ImageView imgTab1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTab);
imgTab1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab_search);
imgTab1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
tv.setText(titles[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);
```